# How best to store information?

Tags: java, database, memory, mobile

I'm writing in Java.

Trying to write my first user time-management mobile app.

I create a user class and a great function which allows the user to create a group of users in which he is admin, from which he has capabilities to track the employees—-

Does it require separate arrays?
Or is there something about databases that I don't yet understand?

Where does all the info from a single user being stored?

Sorry in advance for the noob question.

Comment: What is the issue? Show some code and explain how the behaviour is not as you'd expect.

Comment: Im asking on a theoretical level.

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions possible, you can have a separate table called admin where he has the entries of all of his associated employees (user) and yes programmatically you need to access them via an array. More information like uml diagram will make it more clear.